# In Grails, how do I specify jars needed by an ivy resolver?

Tags: grails, ivy, resolver

In a grails project I have added a custom ivy resolver per the reference docs, http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#12.2%20Plugin%20Repositories .

However, this resolver requires jsch and and some other jars.  How can I put them on the project's build classpath so that ivy will use them?

This is my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

//Configure resolver
def sshResolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver()
['libraries', 'builds'].each {
    sshResolver.addArtifactPattern("/home/ivy/[organisation]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]")
    sshResolver.addIvyPattern("/home/ivy/[organisation]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]")
}
sshResolver.name = "ssh"
sshResolver.settings = ivySettings

resolver sshResolver

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
    }
    log "warn" 
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        ssh()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'someorg:somejar:1.0'
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apparently

```
grails -cp ./lib/jsch.jar
```

was the answer, not the -classpath or --classpath that I had initially tried.

**If anyone has a better answer I will certainly accept it over mine.**

I tried placing the jar in grails/lib but it gets loaded after the resolvers are processed.

I tried this in PreInit.groovy but no luck there either.

```
grails.compiler.dependencies = { fileset(file:'${basedir}/lib/jsch.jar') }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got this answer from the Ian Roberts on the Grails user list which works for me:

```
def myCL = new URLClassLoader([new File(
            "${basedir}/lib/the.jar"
        ).toURI().toURL()] as URL[],
        org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.classLoader)
resolver myCL.loadClass('com.whatever.MyResolver').newInstance()
```

Passing the class loader that loaded Ivy as the parent is important so that it can resolve Ivy classes.

If you need to load multiple jars (because the class you are loading depends on them), then put all the files in the list like so:

```
def myCL = new URLClassLoader([
        "${basedir}/lib/jar1",
        "${basedir}/lib/jar2", // etc.
    ].collect { new File(it).toURI().toURL() } as URL[],
    org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.classLoader)
resolver myCL.loadClass('com.whatever.MyResolver').newInstance()
```

Comment: That's quite clever.  Unfortunately I still get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException  

with

def myCL = new URLClassLoader([new File(
            "${basedir}/lib/jsch-0.1.31.jar"
        ).toURI().toURL()] as URL[],
        org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.classLoader)
resolver  myCL.loadClass('org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver').newInstance()

Oh well.  Good thing I switched to a regular maven repository.

Comment: @gabe, you'd need to add all the required jars to the list. I'll update it for multiple jars.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that seems to work is to use [@Grab](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Grab.html). Something like:

```
@Grab(group="com.jcraft",module="jsch",version="0.1.42")
import org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver

def sshResolver = new SshResolver()
['libraries', 'builds'].each {
    sshResolver.addArtifactPattern("/home/ivy/[organisation]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]")
    sshResolver.addIvyPattern("/home/ivy/[organisation]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]")
}
sshResolver.name = "ssh"
sshResolver.settings = ivySettings

resolver sshResolver
```

If your jar isn't in a public repository, it may be a little trickier.

Answer (score -1):

Grails uses ivy to implement it's dependency management. All you should need to do is declare the extra libraries you need. Have you tried something like this:

```
dependencies {
    ..
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.42'
    ..
}
```

Comment: I tried build 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.42'
Unfortunately it is not a dependency of the project but of the resolver.  So I get the error before the dependencies are processed.