# Grails - Reference Plugin Jar from the plugin's BuildConfig.groovy (Custom Resolver)

Tags: grails, ivy

I have a plugin that loads a custom Ivy resolver. It uses `${basedir}`
to locate the jar file containing the resolver so I can [load it inside
BuildConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999057/in-grails-how-do-i-specify-jars-needed-by-an-ivy-resolver/6346671#6346671) (see the answer for context). That compiles the plugin, but unfortunately, when the plugin is installed in a project,`basedir` becomes the project directory so it can't find the jar. `pluginBasedir` doesn't seem to point to anything, even inside the plugin's BuildConfig.groovy.

Is there any way to figure out the plugin base directory from within a
plugin's BuildConfig.groovy?

Ultimately I just want my custom resolver (in an external jar) to work when compiling the plugin and when compiling any project the plugin is a part of. Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I could come up with was to get my jar into a public Maven repo and use @Grab. e.g.,

```
@Grab(group='com.noahsloan.atg',module="atg-resolver",version="1.0")
import com.noahsloan.atg.ivy.AtgModuleRepository

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    resolver AtgModuleRepository.newResolver
```

From [my plugin](https://github.com/iamnoah/grails-atg-core-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy). I'd still like to know if there is a way to reference `pluginBasedir` from BuildConfig.