# Grails: how to use Maven repo instead of ivy-cache

Tags: maven, grails, maven-2, maven-3, grails-plugin

I need to use Maven Repository instead of ivy-cache, what are the steps I have to do? I tried multiple ways but it not working.

I specified in BuildConfig.groovy

```
 pom true
   repositories {
 inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
 //grailsPlugins()
 //grailsHome()
 //grailsCentral()
```

and I deleted ivy-cache folder, it(run-app) creating again and downloading all jars again. I found some help from here:

[ivysettings.xml: add local maven path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617963/ivysettings-xml-add-local-maven-path)

I did same changes, even there is no result. My changed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\grails-2.1.4\src\grails\ant\ivysettings.xml`. I think I have to copy this file in our application, but I don't know where?

Comment: Have you correctly integrate grails project with maven like described here(http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/commandLine.html#antAndMaven)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I don't think that you can "disable" the ivy-cache. However you can customize its location:

```
grails.dependency.cache.dir = "C:\\.ivy2"
```

As far as I know Grails will not read your ivy settings, you need to plug your resolvers yourself. 
See this SO question : [In Grails, how do I specify jars needed by an ivy resolver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999057/in-grails-how-do-i-specify-jars-needed-by-an-ivy-resolver)

2) If you problem is only related to maven/grails integration, you can try the following screencast(baby steps) that I created : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqGN61hiciE&list=PLYdLfOs5pdSjWsZCZRnYAQAm78nEFYxhd

Then, in your Maven pom.xml, just add your repositories as usual.

In your BuildConfig.groovy, add pom true and remove repositories declarations as well as the dependencies and plugins sections.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    …
    pom true
     ...
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks My dear friend Rimero, Your information helped somuch. Have a wonderful day.